# Android Studio/Intellij - Does anyone know why the screen slightly darkens when the tooltip window pops up?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

Android Studio Flamingo, works fine on Electric Eel. It only occurs in full-screen mode on an external monitor. MBP 18, MacOS Ventura.
[image: img]

Comment: Does screen capture (Cmd + Shift + 5) grab the issue?

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JBR-5849 is connected.

Comment: @NadiaTarashkevich It seems that when the screen capture overlay (and then the recording itself) is active, this issue does not occur.

Comment: please upvote youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JBR-5849 to follow the updates. If possible, please answer additional questions in this ticket.